# Función recursiva en Golang

Tags: funciones, recursión, go

Necesito una función que valide los estatus de pago de un ticket:
-Si hay un ticket fallido
-Recuperar el nuevo ticket
-Si el nuevo ticket esta fallido (regresar al paso anterior)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta encontrar un ticket en status pendiente o pagado, que ampare el pago del concepto y devolver una respuesta en donde me diga si hay adeudo, no hay adeudo, y en caso de que haya adeudo es un adeudo que está pendiente de pago o es un adeudo que el cliente no piensa pagar.

Tengo el siguiente código en donde busca un elemento dentro de un arreglo, sin embargo **no encuentro la manera de hacer la comparación para que me valide el estatus del ticket**, evidentemente no debería usar ese arreglo, pero lo hice a manera de ejemplo

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    status := []string{"FAILED", "PENDING", "CANCELED"} //Aquí debo emplear una variable
    busqueda := "PENDING"                               //Aqui debo poner que busca algun ticket pendiente
    existe := existeElPago(status, busqueda)
    fmt.Printf("Buscando %v en arreglo. ¿Existe? %v\n", busqueda, existe)
}

func existeElPago(status []string, busqueda string) string {
    for _, cadena := range status {
        if cadena == busqueda {
            return "PENDING"
        }
    }
    return "CANCELED"
}
```

Comment: Una cosa es que haya un ciclo, otra muy diferente es que sea recursiva. Y dado el problema, por qué deberíá ser recursiva?

Comment: Pensaba sería la opción más factible, sin embargo ya me enrolle tanto que quizá trabaje mejor con ciclos, de cualquier manera, mientras sea optima